# Is there a URL query string for searching own GitHub Gists?

Tags: github, github-api, gist

Is there a URL query string for searching only **own** GitHub Gists? I wouldn't care if it only worked with public Gists.

The only thing I could find is the URL for searching all public Gists, but that's not very helpful for finding own Gists

```
https://gist.github.com/search?q=hello+world
```

Ultimate goal: quickly searching for own Gists via launcher tools (in my case [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/)) or Chrome search engine shortcuts.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Try searching with `user:<username> hello world`. E.g.

https://gist.github.com/search?q=user%3Adefunkt+hello+world

Comment: Ah interesting. It works, but it only seems to take the content of the gists into account, not the description. Adding something like `description:text` doesn't have an effect either. I could move descriptions (and some kind of pseudo-tags) inside the code as comments, but it feels wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Yep, the description field is currently not searchable. Enabling that is already on the feature request list.

Comment: Now is working, and the search is executed in the description field either. thanks for the solution!

Comment: Github offers a list of prefixes and other search tips from the search page: https://gist.github.com/search

Comment: I suggest creating also a shortcut for chrome search: https://i.imgur.com/vssfdFS.png